# How do I pull and parse the body of an email from outlook with python into a pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, email, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to pull the body of emails from Outlook into a pandas data frame. How do I break the `msg.Body` into lines that I can write to a `csv` and ingest into pandas?

This is what I have so far (and I can use this to print to screen and copy and past to Excel for more manipulation):

```
import win32com.client
import win32com

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNameSpace('MAPI')
FedEx_Claims = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['FedExClaims']

for msg in FedEx_Claims.Items:
    body = msg.Body
    print(body)
```

I've tried forcing the body into a string, but initial testing didn't suggest that it was being treated as a string because I couldn't filter to only include rows with a ":" in them.

```
s_msg = str(body)
for line in s_msg:
    if ':' in line:
        print(s_msg, end='')
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I currently can't access `IMAP`, but I'm asking my IT if that can be changed.

Comment: what you get with `print( body )` and `print( type(body) )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exchangelib` at https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials, Configuration

creds = Credentials(
    username='X', password='X'
)

config = Configuration(server='X.ca', credentials=creds)

account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address="X@gmail.com",
    autodiscover=False, 
    config=config,
    access_type=DELEGATE
)

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    print(item.body)
```

The item.body content will be in html, then use `pandas.read_html` to read/structure the content

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html